# Conditioned probability question

Tags: probability, probability-theory

We choose at random member *X* from the set **{1,2....n}**
then we choose at random a member *Y* from the set **{1,2...X}**
what is the probability for the event: **X=Y**.
the answer should be a function of n.

so choosing an X has 1/n probability and choosing a Y has 1/X probability , but im stuck as to how to continue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$P(Y = X) = \sum_{k=1}^n P(X=k,Y=k) = \sum_{k=1}^n P(Y=k|X=k)\cdot P(X=k)$$

Can you take it from there?

Comment: yeah I think I can take it from here!, youv'e cleared some of the clutter in my mind , thanks!